# Expectation Value and Variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, means

I know the formula for Expectation value is $$E(X)=\sum f_ix_i$$ where $f_i$ denotes the PMF(Probability Mass Function) and Variance is $Var(X)=E((X-m)^2)$ where m is E(X).

But what is really the significance of the above calculations? How do they help us to know more about the probability distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to think of expected value is as "average value."

Imagine you had a coin two faces; one with a 6, and the other with a 7. Suppose further that this coin is *biased*, meaning it doesn't land on the two sides with equal probability. Specifically, suppose it lands on the 7 side with probability $2/3$ and on the 6 side with probability $1/3$.

If you flipped this coin many times (say, 30,000 times), and wrote down the values, what would you get? There's no way of knowing, of course; it would depend on how the coin flips actually landed. But, you know that *about* $2/3$ of the coin flips would result in a 7, and *about* $1/3$ of the coin flips would land on a $6$. So, if you averaged all the coin flips together, the result should be *close to*
$$\frac{20,000 \cdot 7 + 10,000 \cdot 6}{30,000} = \frac 2 3 \cdot 7 + \frac 1 3 \cdot 6$$
which is precisely the formula for the coin's *expected* value, and shows why we should think of it as an average in some sense.

Variance is a bit trickier, but the concept is similar: $(X - \mu)^2$ computes the *squared deviation from the mean*, which is just what it sounds like; it's the gap from $X$ to its own mean, squared. The variance is the *average* squared deviation from the mean in precisely the same sense of averaging as above. The meaning of variance is to measure how far a variable is spread out relative to its own mean.

There are other ways that you could measure a variable's spread relative to its own mean (such as $\mathbb E \left| X - \mu \right|$), but the variance has important algebraic properties that make it a very convenient measure to work with.